# Select from the result of a union query, Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g, union

I am trying to do a select on the result of a union. I am running Oracle 11g. I ran the following query and I get `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`

I looked at a lot of other posts and this should work, however it doesn't for me. Any help will be appreciated.

```
SELECT tbl.name
FROM
(
    SELECT name FROM customer
    UNION
    SELECT name FROM vendor
) AS tbl;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `as`.

```
SELECT tbl.name
FROM
(
    SELECT name FROM customer
    UNION
    SELECT name FROM vendor
) tbl
```

Answer (score 2):

Oracle doesn't support `as` for table aliases.  So, just remove it:

```
SELECT tbl.name
FROM (SELECT name FROM customer
      UNION
      SELECT name FROM vendor
     ) tbl;
```